# Does WebStorm 2016.1.2 supports Ant plugin?

Tags: plugins, ant, build, webstorm

I use new version of WebStorm. How I can enable Ant plugin?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant plugin is not compatible with WebStorm as it requires some Java-specific features that are not available in WebStorm.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16096 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Nopes. They've closed that ticket as 'wontfix' with this comment: "Ant support is available in IntelliJ IDEA and is out of scope for WebStorm: WebStorm supports only JavaSvript build tools."